# How to stop reinstanciating a view using ViewInjectionManager on DevExpress?

Tags: .net, wpf, devexpress

Is there anyone who knows about initialization mechanism about ViewInjectionManager on DevExpress?

Once a view was populated by injection mecahnism, i dont want to recreate same view as a new instance whenever the mechanism try to recreate the view like navigation situation.

Now i am suffering from reinstanciating a view whenever navigating among registered views.
please give me a guide.

Comment: Can you please post some example code ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))?  Include what you've already tried and where exactly you're stuck. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thanks!

Comment: *DevExpress* is a company. Please [edit] your question and specify what library/product you are using.

Answer (score 0):

> ... i don't want to recreate same view as a new instance whenever the
>   mechanism try to recreate the view like navigation situation.

As far as I know the view's recreating depends on request from the specific navigation container. This navigation container can **cache** early-created views and do not send request into the `ViewInjectionService` in this case, **or do not cache** views and send request for these views recreation into the `ViewInjectionService`.
Please check the corresponding cache-options of your navigation container.
(For example, take a look at the [DXTabControl.TabContentCacheMode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfCoreDXTabControl_TabContentCacheModetopic), [FlipView.ItemCacheMode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfWindowsUIFlipView_ItemCacheModetopic) or the [NavigationPage.NavigationCacheMode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfWindowsUINavigationPage_NavigationCacheModetopic) properties).